# Which external sound cards are supported in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, hardware, soundcard, external-soundcard

Rather than try to get an unspecified external sound card to work it would make sense to buy an external sound card which is known to be supported.

Has anyone got an external sound card which worked out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

hardware is supported by the kernel version and not the version of Ubuntu (although they are obviously related).

Hardware lists are user supported and I would encourage everyone to participate in reporting results of hardware support to the various listings.

See:

http://www.h-node.org/home/index/en

http://www.h-node.org/soundcards/catalogue/en

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/test-suite/

Answer (score -1):

are you talking about a usb sound card?

I have a Creative X-FI Titanium Fatal1ty Pro and the sound works.

Comment: Thanks @rat2000. I am talking about a usb external sound card. Your Fatal1ty looks like an internal card.

Comment: Something like the Soundblaster x-fi go.

Comment: Yea mine is an internal one, I didn't use a USB sound card before, but I think it will run just fine on Ubuntu.